# Recursion in Play framework 2.5.X

Tags: recursion, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play template where I loop through a list of objects that have nested lists, and I'm displaying the items iteratively using nested for loops.

-skillList is a List[Skill]

-Skill is an object defined in a model

-skillObject.getChildrenList() return a list[Skill]

What I would like to do is be able to display this but using some type of recursion so that if the level of nesting of mylist changes I don't have to change the whole template. So is there any way to do this in a recursive way ?

```
<div class="custom-dd dd dd-nodrag" id="nestable_list_1">
<ol class="dd-list">
@for(skill <- skillList) {
    <li class="dd-item">
        <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag row">
            <span class="dd-nodrag" id="content_@skill.getCleanUri()"> @skill.getLabel() </span>
        </div>

    <ol class="dd-list">
    @for((child, indexChild) <- skill.getChildrenList().zipWithIndex) {
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="@indexChild">
            <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag row">
                <span id="content_@child.getCleanUri()"> @child.getLabel() </span>
            </div>

            <ol class="dd-list">
            @for((grandChild, indexGrandChild) <- child.getChildrenList().zipWithIndex) {
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="@indexGrandChild">
                    <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag row">
                        <span id="content_@grandChild.getCleanUri()"> @grandChild.getLabel() </span>
                    </div>

                </li>
            }


            <div class="text-left addNew" id="meta-@index"> 
                <span>
                    <button class="btn btn-icon w-xs plusBtn
                    btn-primary waves-effect waves-light toggleButton" data-toggle="modal" 
                    data-target="#custom-width-modal"> <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                    </button> 
                </span>
            </div>
            @(index = index + 1)

            </ol>
            </li>
    }

    </ol>
    </li>
}

</ol>
```

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate template that takes List[Skill] as argument and renders SkillObjects in provided list and children of these SkillObjects. Then use that template at first nested level in your main page template. Like following -

SkillTemplate.scala.html

```
@(skills: List[Skill])()

<ol class="dd-list">
    @for((child, indexChild) <- skills.zipWithIndex) {
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="@indexChild">
            <div class="dd-handle dd-nodrag row">
                <span id="content_@child.getCleanUri()"> @child.getLabel() </span>
            </div>
            @SkillTemplate(child.getChildrenList())
            <div class="text-left addNew" id="meta-@index"> 
              <span>
                  <button class="btn btn-icon w-xs plusBtn
                    btn-primary waves-effect waves-light toggleButton" data-toggle="modal" 
                    data-target="#custom-width-modal"> <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                  </button> 
              </span>
            </div>
            @(index = index + 1)
         </li>   
    }
</ol>
```

I have not been able to test it